# Android: How to pass PrintWriter variable to another Activity?

Tags: android

I know that for passing variables we can use **Intent** and **Bundle**, but I couldn't find a way to pass a **PrintWriter** variable. Any ideas ?

Comment: You can use application class

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible, since the PrintWriter class is not Parcelable. You can either use a singleton or (if possibile) create a new PrintWriter. In the latter case, you should consider that some of the PrintWriter() constructor parameters may be easily attached to an Intent.